# Guidance on user data management and comparison. Javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison

Im looking for someone to point me in the right direction to solve a small project im working on using javascript. The idea is i would like the user to be able to input some raw data (which has been copied and pasted) from a website into a form box or input of some sort on day one and then again on day two etc etc.

What i would like the JS to do is compare the two sets of data and return any changes. For example

Day One Raw Data: (copy and pasted from a website)

```
Welcome
Home
Contact
Info
A
Andy 29 5'9 $3000 low
B
Betty 19 4'8 $2800 low
Bella 23 5'2 £4300 medium
C
Charles 43 5'3 $5000 high
Your local date/time is Thu Jan 11 2018 20:58:14 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time).
Current server date/time is 11-01-2018 | 21:58 
Logout
```

Day Two Raw Data: (copy and pasted from a website)

```
Welcome
Home
Contact
Info
A
Andy 29 5'9 $3200 low
B
Betty 19 4'8 $2900 low
Bella 23 5'2 £3900 high
C
Charles 43 5'3 $7000 high
Carrie 18 5'8 $1000 medium
Your local date/time is Thu Jan 11 2018 20:58:14 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time).
Current server date/time is 11-01-2018 | 21:58 
Logout
```

The only bit of data im looking to compare is the name + information lines

```
 Andy 29 5'9 $3200 low
```

for example. The rest of the raw data is just noise which should always be the same, the links on the top of the page for example and the footer at the bottom also including the A, B,C etc which are alphabet links.

What i would like the outcome to be is something like the following:

Results: (printed to page)

```
Andy 29 5'9 $3200 low --- (+ $200)
Betty 19 4'8 $2900 low --- (+ $100)
Bella 23 5'2 £3900 high --- (- $400 medium)
Charles 43 5'3 $7000 high --- (+ $2000)
Carrie 18 5'8 $1000 medium --- (**New Entry**)
```

How the results are displayed and the actually figures are irrelevant. Im looking for suggestions for methods to actually achieving this kind of data comparisons where i ignore certain parts of the raw input and compare those that are of importance. Report back with the new and removed entries, changes to duplicate entries. The only data that will ever change is the amount of people in the raw data the headers, footers and alphabet tags will always be there.

Hopefully ive explained well enough to get pointed in the right direction. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is messy (its late) but this will do what you want I think...

There is huge room for cleaning this up so take this as a steer in the right direction.  The key is you need regex to analyse the strings. Then there's a fair amount of manipulation to compare the results.

```
<script>
var dayOne = `Welcome
Home
Contact
Info
A
Andy 29 5'9 $3000 low
B
Betty 19 4'8 $2800 low
Bella 23 5'2 £4300 medium
C
Charles 43 5'3 $5000 high
Your local date/time is Thu Jan 11 2018 20:58:14 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time).
Current server date/time is 11-01-2018 | 21:58 
Logout `;

var dayTwo = `

Welcome
Home
Contact
Info
A
Andy 29 5'9 $3200 low
B
Betty 19 4'8 $2900 low
Bella 23 5'2 £3900 high
C
Charles 43 5'3 $7000 high
Carrie 18 5'8 $1000 medium
Your local date/time is Thu Jan 11 2018 20:58:14 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time).
Current server date/time is 11-01-2018 | 21:58 
Logout `;

/**
* Converts an array to an object with keys for later comparison
*/
function convertNamesToKeys(arr){
    var obj = {}
    for(var i=0, j=arr.length; i<j; i+=1){
        var name = arr[i].substring(0,arr[i].indexOf(' '));
        obj[name] = arr[i];
    }
    return obj;
}

/**
* Count object length
*/
function getObjectLength(obj) {
    var length = 0;
    for( var key in obj ) {
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            length+=1;
        }
    }
    return length;
};


/**
* Compares two objects for differences in values
* retains objects with different keys
*/
function compareObjectValue(primaryObject, secondaryObject){

    for(var name in primaryObject){
        if( primaryObject.hasOwnProperty(name) 
            && name in secondaryObject){

            if(primaryObject[name] === secondaryObject[name]){
                delete primaryObject[name];
            }
        }
    }

    //This is your final array which should contain just unique values between the two days
    console.log(primaryObject);

}
//split the large string into lines for manageability and simplicity of regex
var dayOneArray = dayOne.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
var dayTwoArray = dayTwo.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);

//discard any lines which are noise
var regex = /^[a-z\s0-9']+(\$|£)[0-9\sa-z]+$/i
var dayOneFiltered = dayOneArray.filter(line => regex.test(line));
var dayTwoFiltered = dayTwoArray.filter(line => regex.test(line));

//convert the arrays into objects using name as key for easy comparison
var dayOneConverted = convertNamesToKeys(dayOneFiltered);
var dayTwoConverted = convertNamesToKeys(dayTwoFiltered);

//Determine which of the two objects is the larger and loop that one
//We will unset keys which have values that are the same and leave keys 
//in the larger array which must be unique - not sure if you want that?
if( getObjectLength(dayOneConverted) > getObjectLength(dayTwoConverted)){
    compareObjectValue(dayOneConverted, dayTwoConverted)
}
else {
    compareObjectValue(dayTwoConverted, dayOneConverted);
}

</script>
```